# "Abner's hand became a vise and his voice rang as over metal"

Tags: meaning

> But Randolph heard nothing, saw nothing. Only the sun entered. Abner's
>   hand tightened on his arm.
>
> "It is here! Look!" And he pointed to the wall.
>
> Randolph, following the extended finger, saw a tiny brilliant disk of
>   light moving slowly up the wall toward the lock of the fowling piece.
>   Abner's hand became a vise and his voice **rang as over metal**.

It's from *The Doomdorf Mystery* (1918) by Melville Davisson Post.

What's the meaning of "rang as over metal" in this sentence?

Comment: I don't think that "rang as over metal" is a common idiom.  You probably have to interpret it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that his voice sounded as if he was shouting over a large piece of metal --imagine the acoustics in an all-metal room.

It's an odd piece of imagery --it's not hard to picture, but I can't say that I've actually ever heard anyone shouting over a piece of metal, so I don't know how accurate my mental (auditory) image is.

I don't think the author was entirely justified in acting as though it should be a part of our shared experience.  *Rang [out] like a bell* would have been a more common phrase, but perhaps he found that cliched.